# The meaning of stick a finger in the earth?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

What is the meaning of the "stick a finger in the earth"?

> In a way, it harkens back to the beginnings of art itself, when some
>   unknown artist must have **stuck a finger in the earth** to draw an image
>   or maybe he picked up a stone and made a drawing on the wall of a
>   cave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this is saying that one of the earliest humans (the first artist ever) figured out they could make a picture by drawing in the ground with their finger- hence, they stuck their finger in the earth to do so. The material on the ground was most likely something soft like soil or sand or clay. See [this](https://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photography-heart-symbol-drawn-sand-hand-girl-drawing-image32443142) for example.